# Making a $_GET search URL (containing a term) SEO safe without affecting search results?

Tags: php, mysql, seo

I have an existing PHP/MySQL search for my website (which is in production at the moment).

Visitors can search the website via a $_GET form (by entering the search term).

The $_GET URL looks like -> `http://localhost/search/the term` (the reason I'm using $_GET is so the search results can be easily directed too. Also because I have pagination on the search php file which is where `$_GET['term']` becomes usefull (accross the various pages)).

I'm using mod_rewrite for SEO friendly URLs accross the whole site, so I'm worried that having the search URL like this would affect the consistent SEO URL flow of the website...because the visitor could easily enter non alpha-numeric characters....

Appreciate all responses.

Comment: No need to use a SEO URL for your search results (in almost all cases). Just do a URL query: http://localhost/search?q=the+term. Don't know if it's still the case but SE's mostly ignore `?param=something`

Comment: I agree with PeeHaa, Google's URLs looks like http://www.google.com/search?q=hello anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Visitors can search the website via a $_GET form.

That's all right.
BUT search engines DO NOT use your forms!

So, there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: LOL - Must be me over thinking/analyzing, because was thinking if someone posted the direct search URL (to the results) and that got indexed it could be bad for SEO.

Comment: what's bad for seo if someone posted the direct search URL?